# ¿Cómo implementar una validación en un formulario?

Tags: android, android-studio, validación

¿Cómo puedo realizar una validación en mi checkbox?, tengo un editTex con el siguiente mensaje "Para agregar tus datos necesitas aceptar los términos y condiciones.", el cual quiero que salga cuando el usuario quiera intentar agregar o realizar cualquier otra acción con otros elementos antes de realizar el check en términos y condiciones.

Este es mi maqueta de mi activity en donde quiero poner la validación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo la siguiente función pero no me funciona

```
public void validationCheck() {
    check = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isCheked) {
            if (!isCheked) {
                editText.setEnabled(false);
                editText.setFocusable(false);
                editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                tvErrorValidacion.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.error_not_check));
            } else {
                editText.setEnabled(true);
                editText.setFocusable(true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Answer (score 2):

> Tienes que validar si tu checkbox esta seleccionado o no, dependiendo de esto, puedes deshabiliar tus editext o botones , depende con lo que no quieres que el usuario interactue
>
> Ejemplo:
>
> Aqui le dices que si no esta seleccionado tu check, que te deshabilite tus campos, en caso contrario, que te los habilite

```
    if(!myCheckbox.isChecked){
     myEditext1.setEnabled(false)
     myEditext2.setEnabled(false)
    } else {
      myEditext.setEnabled(true)
    }
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).